# Meteor: Showing extra sign up field conditionally using meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using [meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3](https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3)  to create sign up form. In my sign up form i have two options **Doctor** and **Advisor**. If during sign up process user selects doctor i want to show more fields (required fields) based on that selection and if user select advisor those field should remain hidden. Below is my code of sign up form:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
requestPermissions: {},
extraSignupFields: [{
    fieldName: 'phone',
    fieldLabel: 'Phone Number',
    inputType: 'text',
    visible: true,
    validate: function(value, errorFunction) {
      if (!value) {
        errorFunction("Please write your Phone Number");
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
},
{
    fieldName: 'type',
    showFieldLabel: false,
    fieldLabel: 'User Type',
    inputType: 'radio',
    radioLayout: 'vertical', 
    data: [{                    
        id: 1,                  
        label: 'Doctor',          
        value: 'doctor'              
      }, {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Advisor',
        value: 'advisor',
    }],
    validate: function(value, errorFunction){
      if (!value) {
        errorFunction("Please select user type.");
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    visible: true
}, {
    fieldName: 'terms',
    fieldLabel: 'I accept the terms and conditions',
    inputType: 'checkbox',
    visible: true,
    validate: function(value, errorFunction){
      if (value != 'true') {
        errorFunction("You must accept the terms and conditions.");
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    saveToProfile: false
}]
```

});

How can i show more fields if user selects "Doctor" ? How i should i add condition in above code ? For example if radio type field value is doctor i want to show more fields like zip code and date of birth.

Any help will be highly appreciated as i am learning meteor.

Comment: @Alexander how can i show more fields if user selects "Doctor" ? How i should i add condition in above code ? For example if radio type field value is doctor i want show more fields like zip code and date of birth.

Comment: @MohsinRafi Its not possible to do this with accounts-ui. You would have to make your own template and do this manually

Comment: @Mohsin You should update the post and include the actual question there.